# How is "double border" eliminated for stacked inline-block elements by negative margins?

Tags: css

If we place 3 x 3 inline-block elements together, we know their borders will touch each other and "double up":

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px dotted #999;
  font: 42px Arial;
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>4</span><span>5</span><span>6</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>7</span><span>8</span><span>9</span>
</div>
```

If we don't use a table to do it, some developers using a margin-top and margin-left to fix it:

```
margin-top: -3px;
margin-left: -3px;
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px dotted #999;
  font: 42px Arial;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  margin-left: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>4</span><span>5</span><span>6</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>7</span><span>8</span><span>9</span>
</div>
```

The effect with border being 1px:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dotted #999;
  font: 42px Arial;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>4</span><span>5</span><span>6</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>7</span><span>8</span><span>9</span>
</div>
```

But we also know a negative margin "moves the element", similar to

```
position: relative; top: -3px; left: -3px
```

And if the borders "double up", moving every element "relatively" is not going to fix it, supposedly.  So how does negative margin make it work?  Can the claim be substantiated by CSS specs.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned the following code:

```css
position: relative;
top: -3px;
left: -3px;
```

`top: -3px;` moves each element up by 3px.
`left: -3px;` moves each element left by 3px.

The code therefore won't solve your problem because all elements are shifted – the whole grid moves to the top left, and borders still double up.

---

`margin: -3px;` is something different. It positions each box normally, but as if they were all was 3px smaller on each side.

This means each box moves closer to the element adjacent to it, and borders no longer double up.

Comment: can you back it up with the specs?  In a way, the box is like having a height of 60px, but it is like having a height of 57px or 59px... is this "like" behavior in the specs? When it becomes 57px or 59px... it is not called the height, but is there a name for this new value?

Answer (score 0):

`margin` affect the layout while top/left only move the element from its normal flow position without affecting the layout.

Here is a basic example to understand the difference:

```css
.box {
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  border:2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="margin-top:-50px;"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Notice how we shift the second element and the third follow it.

Now let's use `top`

```css
.box {
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  border:2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="top:-50px;position:relative"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

The third will not move. `top` will simply affect the concerned element

---

From the specification:

> relative
>
> The box's position is calculated according to the normal flow (this is called the position in normal flow). Then the box is offset relative to its normal position. When a box B is relatively positioned, **the position of the following box is calculated as though B were not offset.**

For the margin I guess it's more trivial since margin is a part of the box model like defined [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html). You won't find an explicit sentence saying how negative margin behaves but following its logic we can understand that negative margin will affect the box of the concerned element and will affect the adjacent elements.

So negative margin doesn't *really* move the element the same way as top/left.